# Does streaming media in SharePoint pose a performance risk?

Tags: performance, sharepoint, video, streaming

Can anyone comment on the performance implications of storing streaming media in a SharePoint 2007 document library? I’ve heard this can be detrimental to the performance of the farm due to the media being streamed from storage in a SQL DB.

Has anyone had any firsthand experience with this and if so, what alternatives have you used to provide users with the ability to publish and mange their own video content? Assume a secure internal environment so external services like YouTube are not viable in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried this on a test deploy and it had very poor performance.  Not only did the SharePoint server struggle, but the video the client was trying to stream was very laggy.  Granted, we did not have a state of the art server set up, but I was the only one accessing the server and it couldn't even handle that.  Given my experience, I would advise against it.

Comment: Thanks Josh, did you find an alternative method of sharing video?

Comment: I believe we ended up storing the full video files on our file server and simply providing links to the files from our SharePoint pages.  It isn't ideal, but we only wanted a few videos to be available so it worked for us.
I did read SharePoint 2010 will have Silverlight support, so maybe there will be a way to stream video with that.  I haven't looked into SP2010 or Silverlight enough to know what if it will be possible though.

Answer (score 0):

I can stream FLV's for flash movies from a document library with reasonable performance. I still opted for deploying them to a separate non-sharepoint website because the video's where fairly static and do take up a lot of SQL space.

You might consider activating blobcaching to get around the streaming from the database, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa604896.aspx